# Java regex to extract param from function in url string

Tags: java, regex

My string is something like:

```
http://url:port?param1=foo&param2=EDIT[a,b]&param3=fuu&param4=EDIT[c,33]
```

I need a regex to extract:

```
http://url:port?param1=foo&param2=
a
b
&param3=fuu&param4=
c
33
```

For a single repetition of EDIT[] I'm able to use this regex:

```
(.*)EDIT\\[(.+)\\,(.+)\\](.*)
```

But I can't find a working one for a unlimited number of repetition. Something like:

```
((.*)EDIT\\[(.+)\\,(.+)\\](.*)){1,}
```

Comment: From the only example you provided: Split the string on `'EDIT'`, replace square brackets with empty string, and then split on `,` (comma).

Comment: Can you provide the compiled regex?

Answer (score 0):

one solution is to make your very generic selectors non greedy with the `?` sign. In current version, more characters than necessary are captured by your `.+` and `.*`, so they consume the second `EDIT`.

the regex:

```
(.*?)EDIT\[(.+?)\,(.+?)\](.*?)
```

to see it in action: https://regex101.com/r/PuL3SW/1

EDIT: according to the comment, to capture the last part of the url if needed, you can use an alternative (second edit: i also removed the 4th capturing group `(.*?)` that never captured nothing, NOTE: you can be always sure that the last capture `(.+)` will be the end of your URL because anything else that is before an `EDIT` will have been captured before):

```
(.*?)EDIT\[(.+?)\,(.+?)\]|(.+)
```

updated regex here: https://regex101.com/r/PuL3SW/4

Comment: It you try with
`http://url:port?param1=foo&param2=EDIT[a,b]&param3=fuu&param4=EDIT[c,33]&param5=fpp`
it stops working

Comment: updated the regex again to optimize it, don't hesitate to tell if there's another issue